# Internet Explorer external css issue

Tags: css, firefox, internet-explorer-8

I am working on a site ([www.eticket24.at](http://www.eticket24.at/)) and have to create an external CSS for both the header and footer.

If I view the header, for example, seperately in FireFox by going to [www.eticket24.at/header.php](http://www.eticket24.at/header.php), it looks fine — the CSS is all there, and it's styled the way it should be. However, in IE8, if I do the same, the style is gone compeletely. It works on the index page, but not when I view it alone.

I am using **`link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.eticket24.at/et24_header.css`** to include the CSS at the top of my header.php page. Same goes for my footer.php page.

So, what's the problem with Internet Explorer *this* time? Why won't it behave?

Thanks.

Comment: you include your stylesheets in the `body` tag?!

Comment: I included the stylesheets in the body tag because I need the file to be seperate so that another company can safely link to the header.php file alone complete with css styling.

Comment: The header.php include works correctly on the live site because it is inserted into a valid html document.  header.php itself is not a valid html document, but firefox auto corrects this and renders it as one, where as IE does not.  If a future customer wants to use this include, they simply need to include the header file in a valid html document.

Answer (score 1):

It's because when you're vewing the header on its own, Firefox will correct the incomplete markup and make the page a valid html document with the `<html><body>...</body></html>` tags.

IE will not do this, so the styles will not be applied as it doesn't know to do this on an invalid page.

This is also why the page looks correct on the live site.

Comment: I need the file to be seperate so that another company can safely link to the header.php file alone and be complete with css styling. Do I create the <html><body>...</body></html> tags in the header.php file so that IE can understand what's going on. But surely this will cause a problem as there are multiple html and body tags (both to be found in header.php and index.php).

Comment: There is no html tag in the header.php file, which is why it does not render correctly in IE.  If the next company includes that file in a valid html document then it should display correctly, which is also why it's displaying correctly on the current live site.

Answer (score 1):

Your link is inside the body of the page... try putting it inside the `<head />` section.  Also add `type="text/css"` to the `<rel />` tag.

Comment: [You don’t need `type="text/css"`](http://diveintohtml5.org/semantics.html#rel-stylesheet).

Answer (score 1):

header.php doesn’t return a full HTML page, so maybe Internet Explorer is borking on that. Even though Firefox renders it, I don’t think you can necessarily expect all browsers to do so.

As ifaour mentioned, you might want to move your `<link>` tags into the `<head>` tag, as they’re not meant to go in `<body>`.

Answer (score 0):

I included all the css inside the .php files themselves instead of linking them and changed some div names (from  to , and  to . This helped because css styling of the divs before were being overridden by the other companys css styling, so I had to create my own unique div names, instead of the standard HTML5 ones